# elasticsearch version 7.9 cannot upgrade to 8.0.0

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, deployment, yaml, version

the following is my elasticsearch deployment yaml file for version 7.9 :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  replicas: 1 
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: elasticsearch:7.9.0
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 4Gi
          limits:
            memory: 5Gi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
        - containerPort: 9300
        env:
        - name: discovery.type
          value: single-node
```

its quit working fine.But when I try to upgrade the elasticsearch version to 8.0.0 in the same above yaml `image: elasticsearch:8.0.0` , I cannot access my elasticsearch with my URL. Or is there any changes to be made for e.s version 8.0.0.
Below is my service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: esservice
spec:
  selector: 
    app: elasticsearch
  type: NodePort  
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
      nodePort: 31200
```

Comment: the security is enable in elasticsearch 8. are you try to connect with https and user/password?

Comment: no im not..im trying with http

Comment: Do you have some errors?

Comment: yes still i am having

Comment: Please provide more information to the question, including logs, errors, all config files, details about cluster (how to reproduce your problem step by step).